# Finding the vector with minimal integers that keeps the ratio in R

Tags: r, vector, greatest-common-divisor

I'm looking for a function that works for lists or vectors that "normalize" their values in a way that:
1) Finds the minimal integer values of the elements
2) Keeps the source ratio between elements.

For instance:

```
(0.25,0.25,0.5) -> (1, 1, 2)
(0.3, 0.3, 0.4) -> (3, 3, 4)
(1/2, 1/3, 1/6) -> (2, 3, 6)

...
```

We can assume that the source vector elements sum to 1.
In addition, the number of elements in the vector is not limited.
Can GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) or LCD function help in this case?

Comment: a bit confused, how is the minimal integer for .3 not 1?

Comment: oh nevermind I see what you mean.

Comment: In order to keep the ratio between elements - it has to be 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 h=function(a){
  x=a*10**max(nchar(sub(".*\\.","",a)))
  w=1:min(x)
  z=sapply(w,function(y)all(!x%%y))
  d=ifelse(!any(z),1,max(w[z]))
  x/d
 }
 h(c(0.3,0.3,0.4))
[1] 3 3 4
> h(c(0.25,0.25,0.5))
[1] 1 1 2
 h(c(0.25,0.25,0.75,0.9,0.8))
[1]  5  5 15 18 16
```

## EDIT::

```
Ratios=function(a){
  k=function(x)max((w<-seq(min(x)))[sapply(w,function(y)all(!x%%y))])
  l=function(x)ifelse(length(x)>2,l(c(prod(x[1:2])/k(x[1:2]),x[-(1:2)])),prod(x)/k(x))
  x=as.numeric(sub(".*\\/","",as.character(MASS::as.fractions(a))))
  a*l(x)
}
```

The `k` function finds the `GREATEST COMMON DIVISOR` while the `l` function uses this to find the `lcm`. Now I multiply a with the lcm of the denominator

```
Ratios(c(1,0.5,1/3))
[1] 6 3 2
> Ratios(c(1/2,1/3,1/4))
[1] 6 4 3
> Ratios(c(1/2,1/3,1/6))
[1] 3 2 1
> Ratios(c(1/7,0.5,0.4))
[1] 10 35 28
> Ratios(c(1/7,0.5,0.4,9/10,1/9))
[1]  90 315 252 567  70
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Onyambu! Can you please add explanation? In addition, will it work in case of one of the elements is 1/3 for instance or vector (1/3, 1/2, 1/6)?

Comment: How can we elaborate your solution that will work for cases such as (1/2,1/3,1/6)?

Comment: Well that was not the question asked. But will have to think on that

Comment: Maybe if you ask that as a different question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166347/discussion-between-onyambu-and-avi).